# Rails: How to sum total amount per day and over entire period

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to sum total amount per day and over entire period.

And I'd also like to display the amount in each currency.

The display image is as below.

```
Day 1

event_title1-1    USD 1.11
event_title1-2    -
event_title1-3    EUR 2.22
event_title1-4    USD 3.33
event_title1-5    -

Today's total
USD 4.44
EUR 2.22

-------------
Day 2

event_title2-1    EUR 4.44
event_title2-2    SGD 5.55
event_title2-3    -
event_title2-4    -
event_title2-5    EUR 6.66

Today's total
EUR 11.10
SGD 5.55

===========
Grand Total
USD 4.44
EUR 15.54
SGD 5.55
```

Althouhg I should use such as `group` or `sum` and so on, I coundn't understand how to apply them to my code.

So it would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

**My models**

```
class Schedule
  has_many :days, inverse_of: :schedule, dependent: :destroy
end

class Room
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :rooms
  has_many :events, inverse_of: :room, dependent: :destroy
end

class Event
  belongs_to :room, inverse_of: :events
  has_one :schedule, autosave: false, through: :room
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "scedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    ...
  end

  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "room"
    t.integer  "scedule_id"
    t.integer  "day",                  default: 1
    ...
  end

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time     "start_at"
    t.time     "end_at"
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "room_id"
    t.string   "currency"
    t.decimal  "amount"
    ...
  end
```

**schedules_controller.rb**

```
  ...
  def show
    @schedules = Schedule.find(params[:id])
  ...
  end
  ...
```

**views\schedules\show.html.erb**

```
<%= render @schedules %>
```

**views\schedules\ _schedule.html.erb**

```
  <% schedule.rooms.each_with_index do |r, idx| %>

    <div class="day">Day <%= idx + 1 %></div>

    <% r.events.each do |e| %>

       ...

      <%= e.title %>

        <% if e.currency.present? && e.amount.present? %>
          <div align="right">
            <% if e.currency.to_i == 1 %>
             USD
            <% elsif e.currency.to_i == 2 %>
             EUR
            <% elsif e.currency.to_i == 3 %>
             SGD

             ...

            <% end %>

            <%= e.amount %>
          </div>
        <% end %>

      <% end%>

      ...

  <% end%>

<% end%>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Money Gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) for generating the view and functionality for this kind of view.

Hope you can get what you want .

Answer (score 0):

The query you need would be something like:

...`events.group('events.event_day').sum('events.amount')`

It may be helpful to create a Github gist that supplies the most necessary information, as I would assume that the event_day is defined on the events' table, if not you have to reference the `rooms.day`.

An even better approach would be to use Arel which allows you to write more flexibly.